# How would I have this sum print out it works

Tags: javascript, function, sum, console.log

```
function testSum(){
    var expected = 7
    var actual = sum(5, 2)

    if (actual != expected) {
        console.log("It's broken..")
    } else {
        console.log("It works!")
    }
}
```

I don't know how to work this out, please help

Comment: You need to specify what you are expecting to happen. Also provide as much information as possible. In this case, details about sum are valuable.

Comment: i'm just needing any sum function to print out it works, so expecting the sum to equal 7, but using the above method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a `sum` function that takes two numbers and returns the [sum](https://www.google.com/search?q=sum%20definition) i.e.,

> the total amount resulting from the addition of two or more numbers,
> amounts, or items.
> "the sum of two prime numbers"

```js
function sum(a, b) {
    return a + b
}

function testSum() {
    var expected = 7
    var actual = sum(5, 2)
    if (actual != expected) {
        console.log("It's broken..")
    } else {
        console.log("It works!")
    }
}

testSum()
```

Comment: yup this is perfect!

Answer (score 1):

In a python programming language, you can use sum as the sum of array elements such as  `sum(iterable, start)`. However, in javascript sum is "undefined" unless you define that function. Just sum as `2+7`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code gives the expected output after calling the function. Though you haven't provided details on your `sum` function. So I can't speak on whether your `sum` function is returning the correct result.

I gave an example implementation of `sum` that checks whether `a` and `b` are numeric.

```js
function sum(a, b) {
  if (!isNaN(a) && !isNaN(b)) 
  {
    return a + b;
  }
}

function testSum(){
  var expected = 7
  var actual = sum(5,2)

  if (actual != expected) {
      console.log("It's broken..")
  } else {
      console.log("It works!")
  }
}

testSum();
```